# How to plot ROC curves based on mean and standard deviation in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, visualization

How to plot a figure like the photo based on 5 diferent ROC values and mean, and standard deviation are computed from thoes 5 ROC values?
[ROC curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz1Hw.png)

Comment: The image you linked is from the scikit-learn documentation, it is even produced by an example, what is the point of asking if this comes from an example already?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I only have an input ROC array

Comment: That does not answer what I asked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from the [sklearn website](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html) where you need to

- Classification is used for validation of the model.
- Separate training and testing dataset
- Apply CrossValidation on models

  ```
   import numpy as np

   from sklearn import datasets

   # Import some data to play with
   iris = datasets.load_iris()
   X = iris.data
   y = iris.target
   X, y = X[y != 2], y[y != 2]
   n_samples, n_features = X.shape

   # Add noisy features
   random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
   X = np.c_[X, random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)]

   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   from sklearn import svm
   from sklearn.metrics import auc
   from sklearn.metrics import RocCurveDisplay
   from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

   # Run classifier with cross-validation and plot ROC curves
   cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=6)
   classifier = svm.SVC(kernel="linear", probability=True, random_state=random_state)

   tprs = []
   aucs = []
   mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

   fig, ax = plt.subplots()
   for i, (train, test) in enumerate(cv.split(X, y)):
       classifier.fit(X[train], y[train])
       viz = RocCurveDisplay.from_estimator(
           classifier,
           X[test],
           y[test],
           name="ROC fold {}".format(i),
           alpha=0.3,
           lw=1,
           ax=ax,
       )
       interp_tpr = np.interp(mean_fpr, viz.fpr, viz.tpr)
       interp_tpr[0] = 0.0
       tprs.append(interp_tpr)
       aucs.append(viz.roc_auc)

   ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], linestyle="--", lw=2, color="r", label="Chance", alpha=0.8)

   mean_tpr = np.mean(tprs, axis=0)
   mean_tpr[-1] = 1.0
   mean_auc = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)
   std_auc = np.std(aucs)
   ax.plot(
       mean_fpr,
       mean_tpr,
       color="b",
       label=r"Mean ROC (AUC = %0.2f $\pm$ %0.2f)" % (mean_auc, std_auc),
       lw=2,
       alpha=0.8,
   )

   std_tpr = np.std(tprs, axis=0)
   tprs_upper = np.minimum(mean_tpr + std_tpr, 1)
   tprs_lower = np.maximum(mean_tpr - std_tpr, 0)
   ax.fill_between(
       mean_fpr,
       tprs_lower,
       tprs_upper,
       color="grey",
       alpha=0.2,
       label=r"$\pm$ 1 std. dev.",
   )

   ax.set(
       xlim=[-0.05, 1.05],
       ylim=[-0.05, 1.05],
       title="Receiver operating characteristic example",
   )
   ax.legend(loc="lower right")
   plt.show()
  ```

[image]

Comment: @thank you, how about the grey standard deviation area? how to plot them?

Comment: I have updated the code. You can see the example.

Comment: LEt's say I only have an array of ROC = [0.79, 0.79, 0.72, 0.76, 0.80, 0.88]. How do I make the figure above without tprs?

Comment: You need to know the `fpr` and `tpr.` I'm not sure what you mean without `tprs.` If you have them all then you can apply stdev and mean normally.